# AWS Lambda fetch from ActiveMQ topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, aws-lambda

I have an external data source as an ActiveMQ topic. I can only connect and consume messages. They come pretty rarely, about 1 message per 10-30 seconds.

I want to collect all the messages and put them into the database.
Also I'd like to have an active web page that can receive the new messages over WebSockets and draw a chart.

I have a prototype built with Python/Flask/MongoDB/SocketIO, **BUT**...

I would like to use **Amazon AWS** cloud infrastructure to avoid processing the data on servers.

I believe that AWS Lambda can accept the messages and store them into the database (DynamoDB?) and also send a notification (maybe using SQS) being transformed into WebSocket message. (Not everything is clear there yet, maybe simple ajax polling will be enough).

Here is a question: how it would be possible to consume the messages from external ActiveMQ topic and process it with AWS Lambda?

I was looking on Kinesis, but it looks it only supports the data being pushed to it, but not polling for the data by some protocol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lambda as a cron-like facility and poll on a schedule. See [Lambda Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).

Comment: Hmm, this would be a good solution, thanks, but I'd like to get notified as faster as possible after the message arrives. If I poll the queue each 1 minute - it is not too often anyway.. And too lot of useless lambda invocations.

Comment: Lambda is the only possible way to do this with AWS services and no server.  Important to keep in mind, Lambda functions can only be scheduled as tightly as every 5 minutes, but if each invocation actually connected to ActiveMQ and long-polled it (not just checking and disconnecting), immediately servicing every message that arrived for the next 5 minutes, then terminated, you might have a reasonably viable serverless solution there.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea too. But wouldn't it be too expensive if I get charged for a long-working Lambda? I think maybe it is cheaper to have a micro EC2 instance instead with the service consuming the messages and storing them into the database..

Comment: If your priority is to be serverless, then Lambda is probably the way to go. If your priority is cost, then it should be simple enough to compare the cost of running a t2.nano vs periodic Lambda invocations. Note that with Lambda you get a level of HA and resilience included, that you would not get with your single server-based solution.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. I think in this particular case I will use server, but also try lambda and will keep in mind this solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this becomes interesting again with AmazonMQ. They don't have Kinesis streams or anything else (yet), but .. interesting.